# Move Azure database location for offline sync

Tags: sqlite, azure, xamarin, offline-caching

I have been watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsKjJ6ohjSA&t=1942s) tutorial on implementing offline sync in Xamarin using the Azure portal. at `21:15 - 21:32` the tutorial explains that the `getTable(myCoolTable)` method in

`using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore;`

assumes that the location of your database in the Azure portal is at

`/tables/myCoolTable` although you are able to change this if you want. This is fine if you made your cloud database using their `Easy Tables` software but I did not. It is not explained how it is possible to change this path, so that I can point my local SQLite database to sync with my Azure cloud database which is stored in `ClearDB`.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: /tables/myCoolTable is location of only your  url to your table controller which performs operations on "myCoolTable" . which path you want to change?

Comment: I think I must be confused. I thought that this is where my tables should be. I dont think I have implemented a table controller, do you have any links to documentation to do that in C#?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk

this is where you can find c# implementation for mobile app. this can be consumed from any client xamarin/android etc. If you look at this section on this link "How to: Define a table controller" .you should be able to find. please get back if you have queries :)

Comment: Thanks Mandar I'll check it out now :) with this work with MySQL servers?

Comment: AFAIK, the c# mobile app backend works with sql server database via EF by default. Also you could use azure table storage for your data storage, for more details you could refer to [here](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/domainmgr/#nosql-storage-with-the-storagedomainmanager).

Comment: For MySQL, I have checked that [MySQL Connector/Net 6.8.x](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html) could support EF6 and EF5, which may achieve your purpose, but I found the current version for MySQL Connector in azure app service is `6.5.4`.

Comment: If you could not change your data storage to sql database or azure table storage, you need to implement the [DomainManager<TData>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt587815.aspx) by yourself, you could refer to [StorageDomainManager](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Storage/StorageDomainManager.cs).

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I assumed that you could follow this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started) for creating an Azure Mobile App backend (for a simple way you could choose node.js backend which works with easy tables and when you adding new table in easy tables, it would automatically create the node.js backend for the related table. Also you could build the c# backend by yourself and deploy it to your mobile app) and download the Xamarin demo project, then follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-offline-data) to enable offline sync for your mobile app. Additionally, you could refer to adrian hall's book about [Data Access and Offline Sync](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/dataconcepts/) for a better understanding of offline sync.